# Heap Corruption Error while doing bubble sort using dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi i am trying to create a bubble sort using dynamic arrays, the code seems to work but throws an run time error : HEAP Corruption Detected(since i am deleting dynamic arrays in the ...i donot understand why i am getting such an error). Also, the last two elements in the given array get sorted but i get the address displayed for the last element . As i am trying to learn dynamic arrays on my own.Kindly help me understand the error. Thanks in advance !!!

Array = {125,12,2,36,19}

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 void bubblesort(int* a, int length); // for bubble sort//

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

int  size;
cout << " enter the size of array: " << endl;
cin >> size;
int* a = new int[size];
cout <<  "enter the elements in an array: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
cin >> *(a+i);
bubblesort(a, size);
delete[] a;
a = NULL;
return 0;
}

void bubblesort(int* a, int length)
{
int temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (a[i] > a[i+1])
    {
        temp = a[i+1];
        a[i+1] = a[i];
        a[i]= temp;
    }
 }

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
    cout << " The elements are : " << endl;
    cout << a[i] << endl;
     }
}
```

Comment: "*As i am trying to learn dynamic arrays on my own*"  -- Your error has nothing to do with dynamic arrays.  You are running over the bounds of your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As (it was) mentioned in the comments, you're reading outside the array.

```
a[i + 1] = a[i]; //When i == length - 1, this is UB
```

In the last iteration of the `for` loop, you'll overwrite whatever is after the end of the array. An array `a[length]` is only valid from `0` through `length - 1`.

Also, your bubble sort only runs once, while it is supposed to constantly run until all items are sorted.

On a subjective note, `*(a+i)` is identical to, but less readable than, `a[i]`.

Comment: Thank you @James Root i didn't notice the array length for swapping .  I fixed it  and it works fine . Also i have fixed the issue of sorting all the numbers .  But could you kindly `explain` me  why i got the runtime `error ` stating heap corruption ??